# Push notification timing

Tags: php, python-3.x, python-2.7, push-notification

When I am using https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM then I am not able to send push notification to other person with time

We need to send push notification to other person with 1 hours. How can I send push notification with time for 1 hours not all time.

Comment: Tagged with PHP?

Comment: I am using/implementing  so many application for PHP, python etc.